# Summarizing global soil erosion raster data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, zonal-statistics, normalize

Using [ESDAC's Global Soil Erosion data](https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/global-soil-erosion) which is 25km resolution with values representing metric tons lost per hectare per year. I'm trying to summarize by certain regions using [ArcGIS Pro Zonal Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/zonal-statistics.htm) to sum up the estimated soil loss for a region (Central America, for example.  However, I'm not sure what is the best way to create a normalized statistic for the region? Taking a simple mean average seems inaccurate since terrain can vary widely across a region whereas the sum represents overall magnitude... from there I'm looking for a way to normalize it so regions of different sizes can be compared directly (Central America with South America, for example).

Comment: What's your end goal? Is it to understand total soil loss? Soil loss above/below average for a region or type of terrain? Soil loss per unit of area (sq km, etc.)? That might guide you in figuring out the appropriate statistic. Likewise, a landcover dataset and/or DEM could be helpful in sorting out terrain types.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to normalize it so regions of different sizes (and not categorized in the data) can be compared directly (Central America with South America, for example).  Normalized magnitude potentially?

Comment: If your dataset is metric tons lost per hectare per year, why not multiple each cell by pixel size in hectares to get the total metric tons of soil lost. Then you can renormalize that by the area of the region in hectares, to give you a final measurement back in metric tons per hectare per year.